# Expression Blend problem

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

I'm using Expression Blend Preview for .NET 4 (WPF project). I set IsEnabled property to true, but when I compile project or run it button is always disabled. I do something wrong or it's bug in Blend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the container that the button is hosted in is enabled.